# Inserting jQuery and jQuery UI into header with userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, greasemonkey, userscripts

I've been having trouble trying to insert jQuery and jQuery UI into webpage headers through a Greasemonkey userscript I'm working on. Here's how I'm inserting it:

```
var ccst1 = document.createElement("script");
ccst1.id = "ccst1";
ccst1.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
ccst1.type = "text/javascript";
document.head.appendChild(ccst1);
var ccst2 = document.createElement("script");
ccst2.id = "ccst2";
ccst2.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js";
ccst2.type = "text/javascript";
document.head.appendChild(ccst2);
```

The actual insertion process works, but when I've inserted it, using jQuery on the page (e.g. in an html onclick) works, but jQuery UI immediately gives me a "$ is not defined" error AND a "jQuery is not defined" error the second it's inserted. No jQuery UI then works on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a solution to this. It actually did have to do with jQuery not being loaded properly, but none of the other solutions worked for me. Joey Geralnik suggested this, which is working properly:

```
var ccst1 = document.createElement("script");
ccst1.id = "ccst1";
ccst1.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
ccst1.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(ccst1);
function ccst2func() {
    var ccst2 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst2.id = "ccst2";
    ccst2.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js";
    ccst2.type = "text/javascript";
    document.body.appendChild(ccst2);
    ccst2.addEventListener("load", ccst4func, true);
}
ccst1.addEventListener("load", ccst2func, true);

document.body.insertBefore(concealerPanel, document.body.firstChild);

function ccst4func() {
    var ccst4 = document.createElement("script");
    ccst4.id = "ccst4";
    ccst4.type = "text/javascript";
    ccst4.innerHTML = "$('#ccpanelmassiveconstruct').draggable({'handle': '#ccpmchandle', 'constrain': 'parent', 'distance': 20, 'cursor': 'move', 'grid': [10,10], 'scroll': true});\n$('#iframeDragger').resizable();\n$('#ccpmctabs').tabs();";
    document.body.appendChild(ccst4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need is simply a small wait before inserting the new code that requires jQuery.

```
function jQueryReady() {
  if (typeof unsafeWindow.$ == 'undefined') {
    setTimeout(jQueryReady, 100);
  } else {
    loadJQueryUI(); //this is your function or code that depends on jQuery
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the good idea -- I've been looking around a lot and have never seen this suggested. But unfortunately, nothing happens, which means that "$" is always undefined. But jQuery I add onto the page manually (w/firebug) still works! I don't get it at all.

Comment: @BenjaminHarris are you sure? it seems to work fine for me. Did you remember to actually call the `jQueryReady()` function?  What are you trying to do in the section I called `loadJQueryUI()`?

Comment: your answer was definitely closest. Thanks for putting me onto the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Is jquery already defined in the page you are trying to include it into.
Have you tried

```
$.noConflict()
```

Is it inside a naked function

```
(function(){ alert($("#hello"));  })();
```

Comment: jQuery is not already in the page I'm trying to include it into. I have not tried $.noConflict() (I'm not sure how that works and I didn't want to mess up jQuery UI), and can I place a <script src> tag inside existing javascript? Or do you mean "is my code inside a naked function"? In which case the answer would be: my code isn't generating the error -- firebug attributes the error to the <script> tag with the jQuery UI source.

Answer (score 1):

I have two methods to using jQ with my userscripts. The first is to add jQ to the userscript.

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
    $(document).ready( function() {
          // YOUR GM CODE GOES HERE

    });
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

This works, however events can get tricky. What I like to do, if the page already is using jQ (check source) is actually create 2 files. One user.js (the GM script) that injects a  into the head. This second file needs to be hosted somewhere (i use dropbox) but this is where all your bacon is located. You can write your jQ as if you are writing the code for the page and not a GM script.

eg

GM.user.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Name (jQuery)
// @description             description
// @namespace               my twitter page
// @author          me
// @include         http://         
// ==/UserScript==

var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/example.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

example.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     // MY Awesome code here.

});
```

Whichever method you pick, good luck and have fun.